# Conflicting types for enum bool?

Tags: c, enums

I have a program that gives me the error `[Error] conflicting types for 'empty'` and `[Error] conflicting types for 'full'`. I have a hunch that it has something to do with the `enum bool` use (this is the first time I have tried using it). I've looked at other similar questions, that do not help me, were the issue is forgetting to declare a prototype in the program. I have made sure to write my functions before of main.

**This is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char** data; // array of strings represnting the stack
    int top;     // -1 if empty
    int size;
}Stack;

typedef enum { FALSE, TRUE } bool;

Stack* create(){
    Stack *s;
    s = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    s->top = -1;
    s->size = 10;
    s->data = (char**)malloc(s->size*sizeof(char*));
    return s;
}

void deleteStack(Stack* ps){
    while(ps->top = 0){
        free(ps->data[ps->top]);
        ps->top--;
    }
    free(ps->data);
}

void push(Stack* ps, char* str, int* size){ //may need to call realloc bfr completing push
    if(full(ps)){
        char **temp = realloc(ps->data, ps->size*sizeof(char*));
        ps->data == temp;
        printf("Stack capacity has grown from %d to %d elements\n", ps->size**size, ps->size**(++size));
    }
    ps->data[++ps->top] = str;
}

char* pop(Stack* s, int* i){ //returns the string that was removed from the stack
    if(empty(s))
        return NULL;
    printf("#of elements after popping: %d\tstring popped: %s\n", --i, s->data[s->top]);
    return s->data[s->top--];
}

bool empty(Stack s){ // returns true if stack has no elements else false
    if(s.top == -1)
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}

bool full(Stack s){ //returns true if no more room else false
    if(s.top == s.size-1)
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("Assignment 2 Problem 1 by Jasmine Ramirez\n");

    FILE * input = fopen("data_a2.txt", "r");
    if(input == NULL){
        printf("File %s not found.\n", "data_a2.txt");
        return -1;
    }

    Stack *s;
    s = create();
    char str[255];
    int i = 0, size = 1;
    while(fscanf(input, "%[^\n]", str) == 1){
        i++;
        if(strcmp(str, "pop") == 0){
            i--;
            pop(s, &i);
            //printf("#of elements after popping: %d\tstring popped: %s", i, temp);
        }
        else{
            push(s, str, &size);
        }
    }

    deleteStack(s);
    fclose(input);
    return 0;

}
```

**This is the input:** (just in case)

```
to
sure
Be
pop
pop
pop
you
stop
won't
that
feeling
a
have
I
but
on
go
to
much
Not
right
Brilliant
happens
drink
pop
something
and
both
them
Ring
Story
ovaltine
your
pop
pop
Christmas
A
--
pop
pop
pop
pop
```

Ideas? Or am I just completely off?

Comment: Why not use `<stdbool.h>` and `true` and `false` instead of a do-it-yourself `enum`?

Comment: @below_avg_st  The functions empty and full must be declared before their usage. It is the reason for the error.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My professor wants us to use enum.

Comment: BTW `"%[^\n]"` does not accept newline. So The next line is not entered.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yeah it's one of those bad habits I developed when learning c, I always forget about accepting the new line at the end.

Comment: If you're reading lines, use a line-based input function — [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX 
[`readline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readline.html), for example, or a wrapper around these which removes the trailing newline.  Alternatively, do word-based input: just use `%s` which skips leading white space (what was trailing white space on the previous call) but it stops at the next white space.  Using `scanf()` for line-based input is not a good idea; there are too many ways to get it wrong.

Comment: Please tell your professor politely that 21st Century C uses `<stdbool.h>`; only 20th Century C needs to use the `enum`.  If MSVC doesn't support `<stdbool.h>`, it is still stuck in the previous millennium.  Also, if you are going to use the `enum`, you should probably use `typedef enum { false, true } bool;` with lower case constants so that it will be easier to upgrade later.  Indeed, you might even use a `"boolean.h"` header that includes `<stdbool.h>` if it is available and uses the revised `enum` if it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `push()` you have:

```
void push(Stack* ps, char* str, int* size){
    if(full(ps)){
        …
```

This implicitly declares `full` as a function with indeterminate argument list returning an `int`.  You later define it as returning a `bool` — these are different types, and hence you get the error.

Declare or define `full` before you use it.  Similar comments apply to `empty`, but there's an additional problem in that code pointed out by [Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44705910/).

If you use GCC, use options such as `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration` (or as many of them as your version supports) to ensure that you don't run into this again.

Comment: okay so this is just a compiling error? I just have to add this in when I gcc right?

Comment: No; it is a source code error, but the extra GCC options will tell you when you call a function which doesn't have a prior declaration or definition — preventing the use of 'implicit `int`' declarations of functions.  You'd also find that the functions are best made `static` because they're not accessed outside this source file.  If they were accessed from outside, you'd have a header that declared them, and you'd use that header to declare them, both where they're used and where they're defined.

Answer (score 1):

The names `empty` and `full` are used before their declarations. For example

```
char* pop(Stack* s, int* i){ //returns the string that was removed from the stack
    if(empty(s))
       ^^^^^^^^
        return NULL;
    printf("#of elements after popping: %d\tstring popped: %s\n", --i, s->data[s->top]);
    return s->data[s->top--];
}

bool empty(Stack s){ // returns true if stack has no elements else false
    if(s.top == -1)
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}
```

You  must to declare them before their usage.

And moreover for example the function `empty` has the parameter of the type `Stack` while is called with an argument of the type `Stack *`

Comment: @below_avg_st See my appended post.

Comment: @below_avg_st: And that's why you declare functions before you use them!  Function prototypes are your friends; they help you get the code right so that when it compiles cleanly, there's a decent chance it will work.