# Pop in Stack is not popping?

Tags: c, stack

My pop isn't popping the teacher provided the skeleton for this code, I put printf statements and the push seems to be working it just seems to stop when it gets to the word pop. I know I am probably not freeing the memory right so I figured I would fix that later (or maybe that is the problem?) The char** really threw me off on this one.
This is the same problem as this one [Conflicting types for enum bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44705772/conflicting-types-for-enum-bool)
I guess more people in my class are having problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
char** data;    /* Array of strings representing the stack */
int top;        /* Index of the top of the stack.  top is -1 if the stack is 
empty. */
int size;       /* Number of elements that the stack can currently hold */
} Stack;

typedef enum { FALSE, TRUE } bool;

/* function prototypes */
Stack* create();
void deleteStack( Stack* ps );
void push( Stack* ps, char* str );
char* pop( Stack* s);
bool empty( Stack *s );
bool full( Stack *s );

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *in_file = fopen("data_a2.txt", "r");
Stack *s;

printf("CS 2123 Assignment 2\n");

if (in_file == NULL)
{
    printf("File %s not found.\n", "data_a2.txt");
    return -1;
}
    char strBuffer[256];

    s = create();

    while(fscanf(in_file, "%s", strBuffer)!=EOF) {
        printf("%s\n", strBuffer);

        if(strcmp(strBuffer, "pop") == 0) {
            pop(s);
            } else {
                push(s, strBuffer);
            }
        }

   // free(s);



/* Uncomment next line once you get create working */
   // deleteStack( &s );
fclose(in_file);

}

/* create: returns a new empty stack. */
Stack* create(){
    Stack *s;
s = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
s->top = -1;
s->size = 10;
s->data = (char**)malloc(s->size * sizeof(char*));
return s;
}

/* deleteStack: deletes the memory associated with the given stack. */
void deleteStack( Stack* ps ){
while( ps->top>=0 ){
    free( ps->data[ps->top] );
    ps->top--;

}

free( ps->data );
}

/*
 *  push: takes a string parameter which is the value it pushes onto the 
 stack.
 *  It may also need to call realloc to expand the size of the stack before 
completing the push.
*/
void push( Stack* s, char* str ){
   char *newStr;
   newStr = (char*)malloc(256);
   strcpy(str, newStr);
if(full(s)){
    s->size = 10;
    s->data = (char**)realloc(s->data, s->size);
}
s->data[++s->top] = str;
free(newStr);
free(s->data);
//make new str malloc strcpy buffer
//realloc memory here s.data
}

/* pop: returns the string that was removed from the stack. */
char* pop( Stack* s){
    if(empty(s)) {
        return NULL;
    }
printf("# of elements after popping: %d, string popped: %s\n",s->top + 1, s-
>data[s->top]);
return s->data[s->top--];
}

/* empty: returns TRUE if the stack has no elements, otherwise FALSE. */
bool empty( Stack *s ){
if(s->top == -1) {
    return TRUE;
} 
return FALSE;
}

/* full returns TRUE if the stack does not have any room left, otherwise 
FALSE. */
bool full( Stack *s ){
    if (s->top == s->size - 1) {
        return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `s->top - 1` in the printf...

Comment: Your `strcpy` arguments are reversed. Should be `strcpy(newstr, str)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only looked at `push`.

Problems:

- Horrible indenting.
- There's no reason to believe `256` is enough for your string. Use `strlen(str)+1`.
- `strcpy(str, newStr)` should be `strcpy(newStr, str)`.
- `strdup` is more convenient.
- `s->size = 10;` should be `s->size += 10;`.
- When you reallocate, you pass the number of pointers instead of the size they take.
- No point in casting the result of `realloc`. (Same goes for `malloc`.)
- You added `str` instead of `newStr` to the stack.
- Don't free the string you add to the stack!
- Don't free the stack!
- No checks for memory allocation errors. (This isn't fixed below.)

Fixed:

```
void push( Stack* s, const char* str ) {
    if (full(s)) {
        s->size += 10;
        s->data = realloc(s->data, s->size * sizeof(char*));
    }

    s->data[++(s->top)] = strdup(str);
}
```

---

Rest of stack code cleaned up (without explanations):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char** data;  /* Array of strings representing the stack */
    int size;     /* Number of elements that the stack can currently hold */
    int top;      /* Index of the top of the stack (-1 if empty). */
} Stack;

Stack* Stack_new();
void   Stack_delete( Stack* ps );
void   Stack_push( Stack* ps, const char* str );
char*  Stack_pop( Stack* s );
int    Stack_empty( const Stack* s );
int    Stack_full( const Stack* s );

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Stack *s = Stack_new();

    ...
    Stack_push(s, str);
    ...

    ...
    char* str = Stack_pop(s);
    free(str);
    ...

    Stack_delete(s);
    return 0;
}

/* Create a new empty stack. */
Stack* Stack_new() {
    Stack* s = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    s->top = -1;
    s->size = 10;
    s->data = malloc(s->size * sizeof(char*));
    return s;
}

/* Deletes the memory associated with the given stack. */
void Stack_delete( Stack* s ) {
    while ( s->top >= 0 ){
        free( s->data[(s->top)--] );
    }

    free( s->data );
    free( s );
}

/* Pushes a copy of the provided NUL-terminated string unto the stack. */
void Stack_push( Stack* s, const char* str ){
    if (full(s)) {
        s->size += 10;
        s->data = realloc(s->data, s->size * sizeof(char*));
    }

    s->data[++(s->top)] = strdup(str);
}

/* Returns the string that was removed from the stack. */
/* The returned string needs to be freed. */
/* Returns NULL if the stack is empty. */
char* Stack_pop( Stack* s ) {
    if (empty(s)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return s->data[(s->top)--];
}

/* Returns true if the stack is empty. */
int Stack_empty( const Stack* s ) {
    return s->top == -1;
}

/* Returns true if the stack is full. */
int Stack_full( const Stack* s ) {
    return s->top == s->size - 1;
}
```

Note that I didn't add checks for memory allocation errors.

Comment: That's what valgrind is for, thank you that fixed it. This is my professor's second semester teaching data structures. Her specialty is in algorithms. This summer is going to be rough. Thank you!

Comment: Valgrind won't find anything. I meant I don't check if `strdup`, `malloc` or `realloc` return `NULL` (because you ran out of memory). I figured that if you're out of memory, you're screwed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making the exercise more complicated than it is.

Your push:

```
void push( Stack* s, char* str ){
   char *newStr;
   newStr = (char*)malloc(256);
   strcpy(str, newStr);
if(full(s)){
    s->size = 10;
    s->data = (char**)realloc(s->data, s->size);
}
s->data[++s->top] = str;
free(newStr);
free(s->data);
//make new str malloc strcpy buffer
//realloc memory here s.data
}
```

It does a lot more than what is asked.  `push` should accept **any string  defined by the caller** (your `main()`)

Compare to:

```
Stack* create()
{
   Stack* stack = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
   if (!stack)
       return 0;
   stack->size = 128;    // or any size you like...
   stack->top = -1;
   stack->data = malloc(stack->size * sizeof(char*));
   if (!stack->data)
   {
       free(stack);
       return 0;
   }
   return stack;
}

bool push( Stack* ps, char* str )   // I would consider returning an error code
{
    char* str2;
    char** tmp;
    str2 = strdup(str);    // caller of pop() should call free()
    if (!str2)
        return FALSE;      // error condition
    if (full(ps)) {
        tmp = (char**)realloc(ps->data, (ps->size + 10) * sizeof(char*));
        if (!tmp)
            return FALSE;  // this is an error condition.
                           // use return value to inform the caller
        ps->size += 10;
        ps->data = tmp;
    }
    ps->data[++(ps->top)] = str2;  
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Maybe return a boolean to indicate success?

Comment: My understanding is that everything before main() was provided by the professor and define the tasks to execute.

Comment: Even so, I don't think the prof would object to fixing that problem, especially since it can still be called the same way as before.

Answer (score -1):

Wow, there are so many problems with this code, I don't know where to start.

The push method makes no sense to me, you pass a string (which may point to a read-only location), you reserve (rather arbitrarily) 256 bytes of memory, copy this newly uninitialised data to `src` then free the memory again...

You are using `malloc` and `realloc` really badly

```
int size = ???;
int *array = malloc(size * sizeof *array);

int new_size = ???;
int *tmp = realloc(array, new_size * sizeof *array);
if(tmp == NULL)
    // no more memory, array is still alive
    // return

array = tmp;
```

I don't like the overall design of the stack, you should design data structures so that it's clear what you are doing without having to look at code. Give me a couple of minutes and I'll post something similar.

edit:

I retract my example, it was badly design.

Comment: The strcpy was her idea, when I went for help she suggested it. This is not like any stack structure I have found in any textbook or on the internet. It's a total mess.

Comment: @slyalys, You built your stack using an array. Pablo built theirs using a linked list. I don't know why

Comment: @ikegami I know that's not an elegant solution and some might want to stone me to death for that. I always liked linked lists, I guess I can picture them better in my head.

Comment: There are uses for linked lists; they might even seem convenient for stacks, but it seems to me the memory savings are more than lost by the overhead of linked lists. You also lost out on performance. It's not a good match.

Comment: I agree with you. The reason I like them, specially when someone is starting to learn complex data structures is that (at least for me) are easier to visualize. Using an array and handling indices is more efficient but it takes a while until you can wrap your head around, specially when you are a beginner. That was the reason I choose the linked-link approach.

Comment: @ikegami I was talking about my code not Pablos. Sorry if that comment was too vague. I am terrible at malloc and realloc, I have to practice and do more reading.